# Asynctask out a UI thread

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'd like to brand the AsyncTask class for doing something in background updating the caller thread with the progress but with the caller thread != of UI thread.
I've tried that code but the line publishProgress(i) seems have not effect.
Can someone tell me how can I fix it (or what other class can I use else).
Thanks in advance =)

```
 public class MainUI extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Thread t=new Thread(){
                    boolean exit=false;
                    public void run(){
                        Looper.prepare();
                         new DownloadFilesTask().execute();

                         while (!exit){
                             try {
                                Thread.sleep(600);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                         }

                         Log.d("","Exit thread");

                        Looper.loop();
                    }

                    public void exit(){
                        exit=true;
                    }

                    class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Long> {
                        protected Long doInBackground(Void... urls) {
                            long i=0;
                            for (i=0;i<20;i++){
                                 Log.d("",i+" ");
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(500);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                publishProgress(i);
                                }
                            return i;
                        }
                        protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... progress) {
                            Log.d("Test",progress[0]+"");
                                        }

                                        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
                                            exit();
                                        }
                                    }


                                };
                                t.start();


                            }

                        });
                    }





}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a thread to start an ASyncTask is useless and should not be done.
You should read the painless threading document on the android developer site

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Comment: Updated link: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Answer (score 0):

> From the Android Doc :

There are a few threading rules that must be followed for this class to work properly:

**The task instance must be created on the UI thread.**

```
execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.
Do not call onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result), doInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...) manually.
The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)
```

So you can NOT create it outside of the UI Thread. Use Task instead and wrap it in a ThreadPoolExecutor object. Be aware that you need to make it thread-safe when updating the UI by using one of those :

```
Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)
View.post(Runnable)
View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)
```

But once again, Asynctask is useless and I do NOT recommend it.

Regards

Comment: Come on, of course AsyncTask has it's uses. You just have to understand how it works, like any library function/class.